# Typescript allows importing anything from local ts project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a hello world local typescript project. Im able to build it using npx tsc and the outDir (dist), as defined in tsconfig.json, contains my index.d.ts declaration file.

I then install it in a local vue project by listing it as dependency in its package.json using

```
{ 
  ...,
  "my-module": "file:<relative-path>";
}
```

So far so good. The problem is that i can use the import statement in my vue project to import anything and i dont get compile time errors about importing foo from 'my-module' where the only export from there is {hello}.

index.ts (in ts project)

```
const world = 'world';

export function hello(world: string = 'world'): string {
    return `Hello ${world}! `;
}
```

tsconfig.json (in ts project)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

tslint.json (in ts project)

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended",
        "tslint-config-airbnb"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "eofline": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

I would very much like the ts compiler to complain about missing imports in my vue project from my ts project as well, like it does if i try to import foo from 'vue'

Comment: You tagged this as Typescript 2.0, that's 2 major versions old. Whatever your issue is, I'd strongly suggest to upgrade first.

Comment: Thats my bad. It ofcourse a recent version of typescript